# XmlSerializer does not serialize in one specific scenario

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize a fairly simply object graph. I have a `Settings` model with a couple of scalar properties and a List of type `Template`. That `Template` object has 2 string properties ("Name" and "Path"). If I *only* set "Name" on a `Template` instance, and then serialize, it creates the XML file just fine. It deserializes correctly and I'm happy.

Now, if I load a file into memory from a 3rd party DLL and store that file path to the "Path" property, the serializer no longer works. There are no exceptions or errors displayed in Visual Studio's output window.

What could possibly be happening when I load that file that would be preventing me from serializing my data? There are no references to any 3rd party object in my object graph.

```
[Serializable]
public class Settings
{
    public bool ReplicateToolParameters { get; set; }
    public bool CopyTool { get; set; }
    public List<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    public Settings()
    {
        ReplicateToolParameters = false;
        CopyStaticMaskTool = false;
        Templates = new List<Template>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Template
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

My `TemplateView` has a "Load" button that creates an `OpenFileDialog` to select a ".avp" (3rd party vendor's proprietary file type). When I select a file, the .avp is loaded into memory (using a 3rd party object in my view model) and I save the file path to the "Path" property on my `Template` model. If I don't load a file, I can serialize fine. Simply by loading that file, it no longer works.

Comment: Does it fail with *any* path? A [mcve] would be appreciated so that others could reproduce the problem...

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, its sometimes just better to show examples or code, language and terminology are too ambiguous

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, it seems to fail with any path. I'll add my serialization code and the objects being serialized.

Comment: @TheGeneral I've added some code and tried to explain a little more about what's happening.

Comment: Code in question isn't sufficient to answer question. Can you add code where you load file and that stuff?

Comment: Once we can copy and paste the code into a console app and run it, we have a [mcve]. Until then, it is hard to help.

Comment: I cannot really provide a minimal reproducible example since it depends on paid 3rd party DLLs that I cannot include. I believe I am going to have to reach out to that vendor for help, as it's specifically when one of their classes is in use that I see this issue.

Comment: If the code is as posted the repro can’t depend on the 3rd party library.  Just cut and paste the Path value from a failing debug session into your repro.  It is of course possible the the 3rd party library has corrupted your process.

Comment: Possibly `Path` has some characters that are not supported by the XML standard.  Try calling [`XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.verifyxmlchars?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlConvert_VerifyXmlChars_System_String_) on it before serializing.  For instance, maybe the third party toolkit left some null characters in the string.